# Visual servoing with ROS

Tags: ros, opencv, ardrone-autonomy, servo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to develop a visual servoing application using ROS, AR.Drone and ardrone_autonomy package. For that I'm planning on tracking a four red dots target to use as reference for the error function but I'm having some trouble tracking those targets. Here's what I tried so far:

1 - Use cv::HoughCircles and track dots' centroid.
2 - Using some blob detection.

I can segment the dots using both methods but I can't track the dots correctly. Let me explain: As the AR.Drone moves, the image changes (obviously) and the reference dots change position on the image. Then I loose track of which dot is which. This way the error functions eventually won't work throughout servoing.

I want to focus on control problems and not on programming and computer vision right now. So I'd like to know if you have any suggestions for a different approach or even some advice I may be missing on the approach I'm using. Is there any out of the shelf solution for this so I can focus on control at once?

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42408/visual-servoing-with-ros/) by [perr0](https://answers.ros.org/users/3067/perr0/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2012-08-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [visp_tracker](http://www.ros.org/wiki/visp_tracker) package wraps a library meant for visual servoing tasks and tracks objects based on contour lines extracted from images. As you're having problems with data association during tracking it might also make sense to look at AR marker or QR code tracking solutions. With those every marker can be unique. What you could look at are [ar_track_alvar](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ar_track_alvar), [ar_pose](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ar_pose) and [april_tags_node](http://www.ros.org/wiki/april_tags_node).

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2012-08-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For better or for worse, robotics is a field that requires combining knowledge from many other fields. The problem you're referring to is a well-studied topic called tracking. OpenCV has some tracking functionality built in which may work for what you're doing. I would recommend looking at the various [calcOpticalFlow](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html) functions provided by OpenCV.

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2012-08-27

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1